# How do you define a variable with an OR operator in java

Tags: java, variables, operator-keyword

```
private static long permute(byte[] table, int srcWidth, long src) {
    long dst = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
        int srcPos = srcWidth - table[i];
        dst = (dst<<1) | (src>>srcPos & 0x01);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

here dst = (dst<<1) | (src>>srcPos & 0x01); how does this work?? i am assuming | is an OR operator?

Comment: This isn't defining a variable. And `|` is specifically the [bitwise inclusive or operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). What do you want to know when you ask "how does this work"?

Comment: It's shifting `dst` left 1 bit and then performing a bitwise or with `src`. Consider each operation from left to right.

Comment: @AndyTurner can you give a brief explanation of the line which i have tagged specifially at how does this work?

Comment: @user2475511 What specifically do you not understand about it? How the `|` operator works, or how the whole expression fits together? If the latter, remember that `|` just works on two numbers. `dst << 1` is a number, as is `src >>srcPos & 0x01`. This is fundamentally no different than something like `dst = (dst + 1) * ( (src + srcPos) / 0x01)`, except that the operators are different and less familiar.

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about the bitwise "and" and "or" operations are as ways to set (turn on) and reset (turn off) bits in your result.

You think as one operand as your "mask" - ones and zeros that represent what needs to be set or reset. The other operand is going to be "masked" by that "mask". In the following way:

If the operator is `&`, then each bit in the "mask" that is zero is going to be zero in the result. Each bit that is 1 is going to have the value from the other operand.

So for example `result = x & 0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11110111` (that big number is our mask and I'm showing it in binary) is going to have all the bits the same as `x`, except the fourth bit from the right, which is going to be 0, no matter if it's 0 or 1 in `x`.

So doing `&` with a "mask" is considered to be a "bit-reset" operation, or a "zeroing" operation.

For the `|` (or) operator, you can think of it as a "bit-set" operation. Every bit in the mask that is 1 is going to be 1 in the result. Every bit that is 0 is going to have whatever is in the other operand. So in the result, all the bits that were 1 in the mask are going to be set.

For example `result = x | 0b1000` is going to have all the bits that were in x, except the fourth bit from the right, which is going to be 1 regardless of what it was in x.

Writing masks in binary is long and is a pretty recent thing in Java, so you are more likely to see masks written in hexadecimal. In this case `0xfffffff7` for the `&` example, and `0x8` for the `|` example.

Now let's look at your expression with a "mask" point of view:

- `dst<<1` means shifting `dst` by 1. All its bits are moved one position to the left, and the rightmost bit is set to zero. In essence, this is "making room" for something in the rightmost bit.
- In the right parenthesis, the shift operator has precedence, so it is evaluated first. `src` is moved `srcPos` positions to the right. So the bit that was `srcPos+1` places from the right is now the rightmost bit.
- Now we "mask" that with `0x01`. That is, `0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001`. This is an `&` mask, so everything that is not the rightmost bit is going to be zero. Only the rightmost bit is saved. The end result is that it's the bit that used to be in the `srcPos+1` place in `src`, and *only* that bit - all the rests are reset.
- And now we "mask" this with the `dst<<1` thing that we prepared. Since it is an `|` operation, it's a "setting" mask. Our mask only has one significant bit - the one that we didn't erase in the `&` operation. And it is on the rightmost position. If it's 1, it will be 1 in the result, and if it's 0, it will be 0 in the result (because the left operand has zero in that position).

So basically what it does is:

- Push the bits in `dst` to the left.
- Place the bit from the `srcPos` + 1 place from the right in the rightmost bit of it.

If the values in `table` are all unique positions between 0 and `srcWidth`, then this will give you a scrambling of the bits of `src` - in each round one bit will be pushed into `dst` based on the value of `table[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is bitwise OR not a logical OR

A bitwise OR operates on every bit in that long individually.  This changes it's value, which is not the same as defining it.

Breaking down this line:

```
dst = (dst<<1) | (src>>srcPos & 0x01);
```

---

```
dst<<1 // means left shift 1 place.  The same as multiply by 2.  Zeros lowest bit.

src>>srcPos // means right shift srcPos places.  The same as divide by 2 to the srcPos
            // this puts the selected bit in the lowest place

& 0x01 // means set every bit to zero except the rightmost one which will stay the same

(src>>srcPos & 0x01) // means give me the value of the src bit at srcPos

(dst<<1) | (src>>srcPos & 0x01); // means shift dst left and put a src bit at the end
```

Here the bitwise OR works like it's appending a bit.  That only works because the bits that won't be used have been carefully zero'ed on each side.

As the loop goes around `table` is controlling what bit to sample from `src` and whatever it picks is appended to the right end of `dst`.  Thus `table` controls how `src` is permuted.

Answer (score 1):

" | " is Binary OR Operator which copies a bit if it exists in either operand.
as an example :

```
A|B
```

> will give 61 which is 0011 1101.

" || " is called Logical OR Operator. If any of the two operands are non-zero, then the condition becomes true. as an example:

> (A || B) is true.